# Why is my BigQuery Custom Partitioning not working?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have two tables **Table 'A'** which is non-partitioned and **Table 'B'** which is **custom partitioned** on a column `Year` with an interval of 5, `starting integer is 2010` and `ending integer is 2025` .

Schema for table A

> **serial, string, Timestamp**
>   1 | val_1 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00
>   2 | val_2 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00
>   **and so on..**

Schema for table B

> **serial, string, Year, Timestamp**
>   1 | val_1 | 2010 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00
>   2 | val_2 | 2011 |2011-01-01 00:00:00
>   **and so on..**

But when I try to query Table A using the following command

> `SELECT * FROM A WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-01 00:00:00'`

The execution time of the above query is the **same** as the execution time for the **Partitioned Table**

Query For the Partitioned Table

> `SELECT * FROM B WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 2010 AND 2014`

Why is the execution time the same? Is there some mistake in the approach?

Comment: Is the volume of data scanned is the same or not?

Comment: The partitioned table query is consuming 10 MB whereas non-partitioned query is consuming 8.7 MB

Comment: The size difference in normal because you have the year column in addition in the partitioned table. So, do you have data in your table before 2010 and/or after 2015?

Comment: I have data after 2015 and no data before 2010. I tried the same with the whole natality dataset of 21.9 GB. And now it seems to be working! I think since I was trying it on 0.3 million dataset before due to which I was not able to inference the difference.

Comment: Another remark, the partitioning allows you to look into less data (and thus to pay less). Because of processing in parallel, execution duration may not be impacted by a lower quantity of data.

Comment: Yep, that's a fair point. Thank You.